# Search form to submit post data by inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using GODADDY Email Marketing Campaign for marketing . Here I can design my own html template using the designer option. While I am adding the form to provide a search option, system automatically deletes the form tag from templates, then I can't able make search from email. but I am able to get form elements such as input text box and submit buttom but not form start and end tag .

For this I am planning to code  an inline javascript to send post data to the search url . For this I tried little but I am not familiar with inline javascript.

```
<input name="search" type="text">          

<input class="button" onclick="javascript:document.createElement('form');" type="submit" value="Go">
```

Javscript model(Not working based on idea i am created)

```
function search() {
        var theForm;
        theForm = document.createElement('form');
        theForm.action = 'search.php';
        theForm.method = 'post';
        var searchVal = document.getElementsByName('search').value;
        newInput1.name = 'searchVal';
        newInput1.value = searchVal;
        theForm.submit();
    }
```

Expected inline JavaScript is

```
 <input class="button" onclick="javascript: function(){ var theForm;        theForm = document.createElement('form'); theForm.action = 'search.php';  theForm.method = 'post'; var searchVal = document.getElementsByName('search').value; newInput1.name = 'searchVal';   newInput1.value = searchVal;theForm.submit();}" type="submit" value="Go">
```

Comment: Nobody in their right state of mind will let you execute JavaScript when viewing an email – the big email service providers will filter it out when showing a mail in their web interfaces, and most standalone email clients will suppress it too.

Answer (score 0):

If you system really allow you to use JS, try this:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="search" name="search" type="text">
<input class="button" onclick="search();" type="submit" value="Go">
```

**JS:**

```
 function search() {
        var theForm;
        theForm = document.createElement('form');
        theForm.action = 'search.php';
        theForm.method = 'post';
        var searchVal = document.getElementById('search').value;
        newInput1 = document.createElement('input');
        newInput1.name = 'searchVal';
        newInput1.value = searchVal;
        theForm.appendChild(newInput1);
        theForm.submit();
    }
```

Or inline:

```
<input id="search" name="search" type="text">
<input class="button" onclick="var theForm;theForm = document.createElement('form');theForm.action = 'search.php';theForm.method = 'post';var searchVal = document.getElementById('search').value;newInput1 = document.createElement('input');newInput1.name = 'searchVal';newInput1.value = searchVal;theForm.appendChild(newInput1);theForm.submit();" type="submit" value="Go">
```